# Calculate GitHub hottness score

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, github

I'm trying to implement a hottness score for the application i'm currently creating. The app has some github repos with all the data obtained from GH API in the database. I periodically refresh these data (like pull requests count, stargazers count etc) to keep it up-to-date.

I was wondering how to implement my own hottness score but the problem is that my math skills are probably not so high to be able to invent that by myself. So i'm forced to use or adapt someone else solutions. There are not a lot of them for github repos (there are rather formulas for ie. reddit score or hackernews score), i have actually found one here: https://github.com/sendgridlabs/sendgridlabs.github.com/blob/master/index.html and rewriten it to ruby. Here is my code:

```
def calculate_hottness
    week_half_life = 1.146 * (10 ** -9)

    push_delta    = DateTime.now.to_i - repo_pushed_at.to_i
    created_delta = DateTime.now.to_i - repo_created_at.to_i

    push_weight     = 1
    watchers_weight = 1.314 * (10 ** 7)

    hottness  = push_weight * (Math::E ** (-1 * week_half_life * push_delta))
    hottness += watchers_weight * repo_watchers_count / created_delta

    return hottness
  end
```

I'm actually kind of satisfied with how it works but there is one problem - by "hot repos" i don't mean the ones which are popular in general but rather popular in last few days/weeks/months. For example, when using that method, Ruby on Rails repository will always be the hottest one cause it's one of the most popular repos written in ruby, **not because it's trending recently**.

So the question is - how can i improve that method to help me find recently trending repos instead of the ones that are popular "cause they are old and well-known". Maybe it's a matter of changing something in the given method but, to be honest, i'm not quite sure how it works and why someone has implemented it as that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the word _trending_ actually mean to you? How do you define if a repo is or is not trending? If you can answer that, someone should be able to help you make the math work.

Answer (score 1):

You need more data to calculate the type of trending you're describing. Such as how many stars the repo got this day/week/month, with just this you can rank repos based on who got the most stars recently. Same goes for watchers and you can place more of a weight on the watchers score since it's a more direct clue on how popular it is. I haven't delved in the GH API much but the concept would be something like getting a history of the stars/watchers count and if the API doesn't provide that, you'll need to keep that history yourself. Periodically updating the counts and then once a week passes by you can calculate the count increases since last week and be able to find the repos that increased their star/watcher counts the most in the time range.